# Webspehere 6.1 and JNDI for something other than a Datasource

Tags: websphere, jndi

I was wondering: how does one go about configuring WAS if they want to store some confidential information that is not datasource, JMS or Mail related?  I'm looking more for an adhoc JNDI resource (a few Strings) that can be queried at runtime to get both a username and password for a vendor system I need to connect to.

Not being uber familiar with WAS, I'm sort of lost.  In Tomcat [it was a breeze](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/jndi-resources-howto.html). In WAS, I think I'm missing a few concepts, I'm sure it's possible though.

Comment: Have you ever considered properties files?

Comment: I do use properties files, except things like passwords are forbotten from being placed in them. Need the container to manage the connection information.  Essentially our build and deploy system needs to pull everything from SCM, and passwords are allowed in SCM either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WAS JNDI is open to extension using your own URL provider class. The example[here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/0502_botzum/0502_botzum.html) uses the capability to point to property files, but presumably you could instead create a provider that obtained data from a database (or whatever repository you are required to use) instead of a property file.

Answer (score 2):

You can define your own JNDI entries.

Under Environment -> Naming -> Name Space Bindings you can create String binding type, and assign a key and value which can be looked up by the applications.

Is this what you are after?

Manglu

Comment: Possibly!  I'll give it a try.